# Windows 7 account login error

Tags: windows-7, windows, passwords, user-accounts

Hello I have an issue with my windows 7 PC from ASUS

You see every time I put a password on my account at the login screen the next time I boot up it shows as invalid and that there is no such account. Almost as if it does not exist but i know that it exist. then i put in my account name and username and password and am able to get through but the next time i boot up the the same thing happens again.

I have tried doing two things with this issue 
1) Make a new account deleting the old account and moving the files and placing a password only to have it fail in my face.

2) Doing a windows Restore to recover up to a point where I knew that the account was still working.

Up until now i have kept my account without a password and have been able to get in fine but now it leaves my computer unprotected from anyone logging into my account.

Is there a way to restore or reset the Windows 7 account manager or something like that or to start fresh. I don't know anything about this issue and would like to have someone point me in the right direction.

Thank you and hope for some really great answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are currently using auto login function, but there is no valid account found, to disable it, Run `Command Prompt` as administrator, enter `control userpasswords2`, check the `User must enter....`, click OK

To user auto login with correct login credential, check the box again and click ok, it will prompt you for the login username and password

[image]